# matlab: `hold off` statement changes FigureNextplot property permanently when 'add' is not the default

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I set the default FigureNextplot property to 'new', as opposed to the factory default 'add':

```
set(groot, 'DefaultFigureNextplot', 'new')
```

When using `hold on` Matlab sets the FigureNextplot and AxesNextplot properties to 'add', as it should. However, when I then finish working on the graph, `hold off` resets the AxesNextplot property, but not the FigureNextplot property.

What is the reasoning behind this? Is there a way to keep using my default setting without ridding my codes of all `hold` statements?

Comment: Possibly the reason is that they preferred not assuming much, and only changing these properties when strictly needed. To change, `hold off` would need to have some sort of history of previous values of the property, which makes the function MUCH more difficult, as its suddenly not a standalone function.

Comment: It is worth noting that this behaviour is at least documented; see at the end of [`hold` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)

Comment: Why would you ever use `hold off`, as opposed to, say, `cla` before starting a new plot? `hold off` is for interactive work. In a script or function it should always be on, since it’s so much easier to control things when you explicitly clear the axes.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I agree with you, but `cla` does not change the Figure properties. The problem really is in the `hold on`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a workaround to prevent the figure's `NextPlot` property from being changed:

- Intercept the call to `hold` by saving the following user-defined function in a file named `hold.m`, placing that file in a user folder and adding that folder to the path with `addpath`.
- This user-defined function takes note of the figure's `NextPlot` property, calls the original `hold` function, and then restores the figure's `NextPlot` property.

```
function hold(varargin)

fnp = get(gcf, 'NextPlot'); % get figure's NextPlot property
w = which('hold' ,'-all'); % paths to the modified and original hold functions
dir = pwd; % take note of current folder
cd(fileparts(w{2})); % change to folder of original hold function
oh = @hold; % get a handle to that function
cd(dir) % restore folder
feval(oh, varargin{:}) % call original hold function
set(gcf, 'NextPlot', fnp); % set figure's NextPlot property to its previous value
```

Note that if you call `hold` *without arguments* to toggle the hold state between `on` and `off`, the `on` state is recognized as both the figure's and axis' `NextPlot` properties having the values `add`. This can be seen in the code of the original `hold` function:

> ```
> nexta = get(ax,'NextPlot');
> nextf = get(fig,'NextPlot');
> hold_state = strcmp(nexta,'add') && strcmp(nextf,'add');
> ```

Therefore, if the figure's `NextPlot` property has the value `New`, the `hold` state is always considered to be `off`, regardless of value of the axis' `NextPlot` property. Thus a call to `hold` without arguments always results in the plot being held.

Comment: +1 for figuring this out. But I don’t like the idea of shadowing a standard function. This is bound to cause confusion at some point.

Comment: @Cris Agreed. If you have a better suggestion…

Comment: Can you not use [`builtin()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html) to call the built-in version of `hold` after intercepting to avoid the path-juggling?

Comment: @Wolfie I tried, but `builtin` doesn't work in the case. It works for truly builtin functions, and if I remember correctly also for some non-builtin ones. But `hold` is not a builtin function (it is implemented as an m-file), and unfortunately `builtin` doesn't work for it